# Asp.net MVC 5 make controller action to accept rest type parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a ASP.NET MVC5 application and I have written a new controller action in one of the controller.

I have a scenario where I to want call this new controller action from a different application(React).

Below is my new controller action.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> NewAction(int Id)
{
    var project = await _repository.GetProjectFromIdAsync(Id);
    if (project == null) return HttpNotFound();
    return RedirectToAction("ExistingAction", new { id = project.Id });
}
```

I can invoke the action successfully with this url - `https://myapplicationlink/ControllerName/NewAction?Id=30`

But I want to invoke the action with rest type url like 
`https://myapplicationlink/ControllerName/NewAction/30`

But when I do this I'm getting an error

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Id'of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult] NewAction(Int32)'

How do I make the action to accept rest type URL?

Comment: Check either the convention-based or attribute route template to make sure that it matches the desired format

Comment: It looks proper. There are no attribute routes and the conventional route configured with   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}". And also I could invoke other actions of the same controller with rest type url.

Comment: the parameter names in the route template placeholders are case sensitive. You have  `Id` *(upper-case I)* while the template as `id` *(lower case)*. Rename the parameter to match route template `Task<ActionResult> NewAction(int id) { ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter names in the route template placeholders are case sensitive.

You have  `Id` *(upper-case I)* while the template as `id` *(lower case)*.

This does not match the `{controller}/{action}/{id}` route template

Rename the parameter to match route template `Task<ActionResult> NewAction(int id) { ....`

```
public async Task<ActionResult> NewAction(int id) {
    var project = await _repository.GetProjectFromIdAsync(id);
    if (project == null) return HttpNotFound();
    return RedirectToAction("ExistingAction", new { id = project.Id });
}
```

Comment: Although this solved my problem. I wanted to have a specific name instead of just id like externalId. Because there are two id's are involved here. This would be clear to other devs who are reading this code. So I added an attribute route additionally to this action like [Route("Controller/NewAction/{externalId:int}")]. This worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you have configured routing `{controller}/{action}/{id}`.

Then rename the `Id`parameter name to `id`.